# Is it somehow possible to mark that an answer really worked for the OP?

Tags: discussion

I'm wondering if it is somehow possible to mark those answers which really worked for the OP? PMSE is a bit different than SO, because on SO you can easily check out the answer, and when it works, one simply accepts it. Here on PMSE, trying out the answer is usually not trivial and takes some time. Additionally, accepting an answer is more like a "like" on facebook.

Maybe it is not possible to have another checkbox, but what about a tag, a flag or something else.

For example, I would like to know whether this [answer](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/6059/468) worked or not.

What do you think?

Comment: I've seen M0N4K0 in our chat room before. You could @ping her in the chat room (just load up enough transcripts so that a previous message from her is visible in the room, then you could ping her. I'd love to see our chat room get used more for discussions about how an answer worked out! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The green checkbox is supposed to indicate that the answer solved the askers problem, and there is no expiration on this privilege for the asker. As long as the question is not deleted, the asker can accept an answer, days, months, and even years into the future.

I'd advise askers to wait before accepting answers to see if the answer actually worked.

Furthermore, if the answer doesn't solve the problem, the asker could unaccept the answer, edit the question to bump it back to the top of the queue, and even consider posting a bounty or encouraging another user to post a bounty.

I don't see Stack Exchange adding another flag or checkbox, especially when one already exists. ;)

Comment: I didn't know that unaccept works. Is it something new? Anyway, thanks for the reply.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's always been like that. Mouseover the check mark and you should be able to toggle it again ;)  Votes, on the other hand, are locked in after 5 minutes, unless the post is edited, then the vote can be changed.